# How to get the URL of a youtube video to download it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, youtube, youtube-api, wget

I want download this video on my PC ( also in HD format ): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4RiUy23e9s

So I want the URL of the .flv, .avi, .mp4 or whatever to download it with wget or other download manager.
How can I do this ?

I don't want get the url throught programs o webtools like keepvids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use wget, along with the youtube video url and append a fmt=22 for 720p or fmt=387 for 1080p

Comment: Something may have changed, I've found this link which may be enough to explain your situation:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=66bc2a57362400b2&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

1.Right click on video and select 'pop out'.

2.Wait for the video to start buffering.

3.Right click on the video and select 'Save video as'.

Comment: What video format is the downloaded file encoded in? I was able to download a 375MB video using this method, but wasn't able to play it (I tried .flv, .mp4 and .avi extensions on Mac).

Comment: I tried 'open with' the file with VLC media player and its working fine.
Don't have any idea for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Firefox addon called [EmbeddedObjects](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5258/) which when I'm on that page lets me know there is something to download and it downloads the actual file behind the flash file as an avi.

Comment: Ah I'm very sorry, I think you've added the comment in since my original post but I can't say I saw the comment about not using webtools...

Answer (score 0):

a post that describes what you want:

http://www.kmcgraphics.com/bits-of-code/how-to-get-the-direct-url-path-to-flv-video-files-on-youtube-for-free/

---

Edit:

To get the FLV Url in your application, check out:
http://geniusofevil.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/howto-get-direct-youtube-video-flv-url/

Comment: very userful but I want to get the url without program o webtools like keepvids :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

#
##    ,:,  Download Youtube videos and music using wget
##    Script Name : youtube_wget_video.pl
##    Version     : 0.34
##    Valid from  : May 2013
##    OS Support  : Linux, Mac OSX, OpenBSD, FreeBSD or any system with perl
#                `:`
## Two arguments
##    $1 Youtube URL from the browser
##    $2 prefix to the file name of the video (optional)
#

############  options  ##########################################

# Option: what file type do you want to download? The string is used to search
# in the youtube URL so you can choose mp4, webm, avi or flv.  mp4 seems to
# work on the most players like android, ipod, ipad, iphones, vlc and mplayer.
my $fileType = "mp4";

# Option: what visual resolution or quality do you want to download? List
# multiple values just in case the highest quality video is not available, the
# script will look for the next resolution. You can choose "highres" for 4k
# (4096x2304), "hd1080" for 1080p, "hd720" for 720p, "itag=18" which means
# standard definition 640x380 and "itag=17" which is mobile resolution 144p
# (176x144). The script will always prefer to download the highest resolution
# video format from the list if available. Do not download highres 4k content
# unless you have a 4k tv. That would just be silly.
my $resolution = "hd1080,hd720,itag=18";

# Option: How many times should the script retry the download if wget fails for
# any reason? Do not make this too high as a reoccurring error will just hit
# youtube over and over again. A value of 3 to 10 works well.
my $retryTimes = 5;

# Option: do you want the resolution of the video in the file name? zero(0) is
# no and one(1) is yes. This option simply puts "_hd1080.mp4" or similar at the
# end of the file name.
my $resolutionFilename = 0;

# Option: turn on DEBUG mode. Use this to reverse engineering this code if you are
# making changes or you are building your own youtube download script.
my $DEBUG=0;

#################################################################

## clear the environment and set our path
$ENV{ENV} ="";
$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin";

## initialize retry loop and resolution variables
my $prefix = "";
my $retry = 1;
my $retryCounter = 0;
my $resFile = "unknown";
my $user_url = "";
my $user_prefix = "";
my $url = "";

## collect the URL from the command line argument and untaint the input
if (defined($ARGV[0])) {
    chomp($user_url = $ARGV[0]);
    $url = "$1" if ($user_url =~ m/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\&\?\=\:\.\/\_]+)$/ or die "\nError: Illegal characters in YouTube URL\n\n" );
} else {
    print "\nError: You Must specify a Youtube URL\n\n";
    exit;
}

## declare the user defined file name prefix if specified and untaint the input
if (defined($ARGV[1])) {
   chomp($user_prefix = $ARGV[1]);
   $prefix = "$1" if ($user_prefix =~ m/^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.\ ]+)$/ or die "\nError: Illegal characters in filename prefix\n\n" );
}

## retry getting the video if the script fails for any reason
while ( $retry != 0 && $retryCounter < $retryTimes ) {

## download the html code from the youtube page suppling the page title and the
## video url. The page title will be used for the local video file name and the
## url will be sanitized and passed to wget for the download.
my $html = `wget -Ncq -e convert-links=off --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /dev/null --no-check-certificate "$url" -O-`  or die  "\nThere was a problem downloading the HTML file or the video is not open to the public.\n\n";

## format the title of the page to use as the file name
my ($title) = $html =~ m/<title>(.+)<\/title>/si;
$title =~ s/[^\w\d]+/_/g or die "\nError: title of the HTML page not found. Check the URL.\n\n";
$title =~ s/_youtube//ig;
$title =~ s/^_//ig;
$title = lc ($title);
$title =~ s/_amp//ig;

## collect the URL of the video from the HTML page
my ($download) = $html =~ /"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"(.*)/ig;

# Print all of the separated strings in the HTML page
print "\n$download\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

# This is where we look through the HTML code and select the file type and
# video quality. 
my @urls = split(',', $download);
OUTERLOOP:
foreach my $val (@urls) {
#   print "\n$val\n\n";

    if ( $val =~ /$fileType/ ) {
       my @res = split(',', $resolution);
       foreach my $ress (@res) {
         if ( $val =~ /$ress/ ) {
         print "\n\nGOOD\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
         print "$val\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
         $resFile = $ress;
         $resFile = "sd640" if ( $ress =~ /itag=18/ );
         $resFile = "mb144" if ( $ress =~ /itag=17/ );
         $download = $val;
         last OUTERLOOP;
         }
       }
    }
}

## clean up the url by translating unicode and removing unwanted strings
$download =~ s/\:\ \"//;
$download =~ s/%3A/:/g;
$download =~ s/%2F/\//g;
$download =~ s/%3F/\?/g;
$download =~ s/%3D/\=/g;
$download =~ s/%252C/%2C/g;
$download =~ s/%26/\&/g;
$download =~ s/sig=/signature=/g;
$download =~ s/\\u0026/\&/g;
$download =~ s/(type=[^&]+)//g;
$download =~ s/(fallback_host=[^&]+)//g;
$download =~ s/(quality=[^&]+)//g;

## collect the url and sig since the html page randomizes their order
my ($signature) = $download =~ /(signature=[^&]+)/;
my ($youtubeurl) = $download =~ /(http?:.+)/;
$youtubeurl =~ s/&signature.+$//;

## combine the url and sig in order
$download = "$youtubeurl\&$signature";

## a bit more cleanup as youtube 
$download =~ s/&+/&/g;
$download =~ s/&itag=\d+&signature=/&signature=/g;

## combine file variables into the full file name
my $filename = "unknown";
if ( $resolutionFilename == 1 ) {
   $filename = "$prefix$title\_$resFile.$fileType";
  } else {
   $filename = "$prefix$title.$fileType";
}

## Process check: Are we currently downloading this exact same video? Two of the
## same wget processes will overwrite themselves and corrupt the video.
my $running = `ps auwww | grep [w]get | grep -c "$filename"`;
print "\nNumber of the same wgets running: $running\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
if ($running >= 1)
  {
   print "\nAlready downloading the same filename, exiting: $filename\n";
   exit 0;
  };

## Print the long, sanitized youtube url for testing and debugging
print "\n$download\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

## print the file name of the video collected from the web page title for us to see on the cli
print "\n Download: $filename\n\n";

## Background the script. Use "ps" if you need to look for the process
## running or use "ls -al" to look at the file size and date.
fork and exit;

## Download the video 
system("wget", "-Ncq", "-e", "convert-links=off", "--load-cookies", "/dev/null", "--tries=200", "--timeout=20", "--no-check-certificate", "$download", "-O", "$filename");

## Print the error code of wget
print "     error code: $?\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

## Exit Status: Check if the file exists and we received the correct error code
## from system call. If the download experienced any problems the script will run again and try
## continue the download till the file is downloaded.

if( $? == 0 && -e "$filename" && ! -z "$filename" )
   {
      print " Finished: $filename\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
      $retry = 0;
   }
 else
   {
     print STDERR "\n FAILED: $filename\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
    $retry = 1;
    $retryCounter++;
    sleep $retryCounter;
   }
}

#### EOF #####
```